# Editing RDL files with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, rdl

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express on two workstations.
On one workstation, it has updated the VS2008 installation so that I can create reporting projects containing reports as *.rdl files. On the other workstations, VS2008 can only create/edit *.rdlc files. The report edition interface is also different.

I do not understand where the difference comes from. Two major differences between the two workstations are:
 - one is x86 and had no VS installation before installing SQL Server 2008 Express
 - the other one is x64 and had VS2005 and VS2008 previously installed

I feel like on the second workstation the SQL Server installer updated VS2005 instead of VS2008.

My understanding is that rdlc files are more recent and somehow probably better, but I'd like to edit rdl file for compatibility purpose and also because I'm used to this user interface.

Any advice?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Business Intelligence Design Studio is what allows you to create RDL files.  It installs from the SQL Server installer, but actually modifies the install of Visual Studio such that you can create SSRS specific projects.

Here's another Stack Overflow question on RDLC vs. RDL:

[When to use RDLC over RDL reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079162/when-to-use-rdlc-over-rdl-reports)

Which points to this thread with more information:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1173578.aspx

See also:

http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

Question 10 on GotReportViewer is "What is the difference between RDL and RDLC formats?"

Comment: Thanks for the input. Somehow the SQL Server installer did not update VS2008 (it updated VS2005 that was installed on the same machine though). Running the setup again won't work because it says everything is installed already. Do you know any way to force the install of the BI tools for VS2008?