# how to use rdl/rdlc in my asp.net project to generate a report?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, rdlc, rdl

I have a web application which will use MS ReportViewer. I have another team create a rdl file for me. I renamed the rdl to rdlc and added to my project. And I created a DataSet1.xsd to get the data needed by this rdlc. In my aspx page, I added a ReportViewer control, and set its report property to the rdlc file.

My questions are:

(1) Is it possible to edit the rdl/rdlc in vs2008? When I open it, it is opened as a xml file.

(2) how do I assign the dataset1 to the data source property of the ReportViewer control? When I right click the reportviewer, select the choose data sources, the dataset1 was not listed. Do I have to do this in the code behind?

(3) I got following error The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ans..

1. Yes it is possible to edit rdlc report in vs2008. I don`t know about rdl.
2. See [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1078860.aspx/1) link for step by step solution for 2nd problem.
3. I think this problem is due to wrong conversation from rdl to rdlc. Please follow the step as specified in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Limbani has done a good job answering issues 2 and 3.  I believe your first problem may have to do with Business Intelligence Design Studio not being installed on your development PC.  See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321045/editing-rdl-files-with-visual-studio-2008?rq=1) for more details.