# How to generate an RDLC file using C# during runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm doing some application development (CRM solution) which require 
generating diagrammatically an **[RDLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079162/when-to-use-rdlc-over-rdl-reports)** file at runtime. How do I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use 'Generate RDLC dynamically - Table' example from [got reportviewer?](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) page

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the response from all who answered this question, but I found one good article to generate dynamic reports: [Dynamic Reports with Reporting Services](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/DynamicReports.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Can I confirm that you are trying to build a dynamic reporting solution based on RDLC, or do you just need to mine the data stored in the CRM and show it in a RDLC. I guess you've exhausted other tools such as Proclarity and Excel for users to mine data.

Assuming the former (i.e. an RDLC designer), then RDLC is just an XML file, so I guess you could create simple, standard RDLC's containing datasources, field definitions, cells etc by applying an XSLT after first exporting some kind of xml 'model' from your designer?

Sounds like a lot of work ;)

Answer (score 1):

ALL you have to do is change the the data source by coding.
like

```
        ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;


        ReportDataSource RDS = new ReportDataSource();
        RDS.Name = "DataSet";


        RDS.Value = itemReportTableBindingSource;
        ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "RFID.Reports.ItemsReport.rdlc";
        ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS);

        this.itemReportTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.reportsDataSet.ItemReportTable);
        this.ReportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consult this link it might be helpful

[How to dynamically add new columns to report created with Reporting Services?](http://dobrzanski.net/2009/02/06/how-to-dynamically-add-new-columns-to-report-created-with-reporting-services/)

RDLC Report is a XML file and by editing it in XMLDocument you can modify locate /Report/Body/ReportItems/Table node and do the following inside it

- define the header of a new column – add a new TableCell inside Header node
- bind the column with data (from DataTable) – add a new TableCell inside Details node
- define the width of the colum – add a new TableColumn inside TableColumns