# How to create SSRS report in ASP.NET locally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reporting

I am using `ASP.NET/C#`.

For the first time I am doing `Reporting` in `ASP.NET`.

I created a sample `Report` following  **[this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210608190111/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031605-1.aspx)**.

As far as I understood it requires a seperate `Report server` to be created for this to work.We don't want to create seperate `Reporting server`.

Can anyone guide me as to how I can create `SSRS Reports` locally without creating a seperate server?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2005 report designer supports locally executed reports, which have an RDLC extension.

Here's a [tutorial](http://arcanecode.com/2009/02/09/using-a-local-reporting-services-2008-report-with-an-adonet-data-set/)

MSDN: [Creating Client Report Definition Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Also see [When to use RDLC over RDL reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079162/when-to-use-rdlc-over-rdl-reports).

Comment: If I am to use it locally then I need to use .rdlc file right?This link explains it well http://dinesql.blogspot.in/2010/11/reporting-services-difference-between.html

Comment: Never done it personally, but yes.  Looks like you could do it in vs2005 too; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks I am trying the link.Will get back to you if I need further help.Thanks.