# How to apply custom paging in RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, report, rdlc, rdl

I am having report, that has thousands of records. At the first it loads all the data, and it takes so much time to fetch data.

Is there any way to apply my own logic for paging.

**For Example**

At the first Only 10 records must be displayed and when i click on next button another 10 records displayed.I mean to say on every action only 10 records must be fetched from the database.

Comment: I recommend checking out the [answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079162/when-to-use-rdlc-over-rdl-reports). It sounds like you want a RDL rather than and RDLC (which is client-based). Then you could perform the paging on the server like you are requesting.

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Comment: Actually i am using PostgreSQl as my back end, so is it possible to use rdl?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 0**

Resources for RDL and PostgreSQL:

- [Creating Reports (.RDL Files) Manually - SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.sqlines.com/articles/ssrs/rdl_manually)
- [PostgreSQL Connection](https://github.com/majorsilence/My-FyiReporting/wiki/PostgreSQL-Connection)

---

You are interested in RDL which is the server side portion of the reporting services.

> RDL files are created by the SQL Server 2005 version of Report
>   Designer. RDLC files are created by the Visual Studio 2008 version of
>   Report Designer.
>
> RDL and RDLC formats have the same XML schema. However, in RDLC files,
>   some values (such as query text) are allowed to be empty, which means
>   that they are not immediately ready to be published to a Report
>   Server. The missing values can be entered by opening the RDLC file
>   using the SQL Server 2005 version of Report Designer. (You have to
>   rename .rdlc to .rdl first.)

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/2918209/1085891

**Pagination Resources**

- [Controlling Report Pagination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156282%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [Understanding Pagination in Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677374%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

**Understanding RDLC and RDL**

- [When to use RDLC over RDL reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079162/when-to-use-rdlc-over-rdl-reports)
- [ASP.NET reporting, what, how and when to use RDLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921672/asp-net-reporting-what-how-and-when-to-use-rdlc)