# Script task to run SSRS from SSIS when they are in the same VS solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssis

My question is this: how can I use a script task in an SSIS package to run/save off a PDF from an SSRS report when both the package and the report are in the same solution in Visual Studio? I feel like that should be really simple since they are in the same place, but this is my first time writing a script task and the internet has been surprisingly unhelpful. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something I've dabbled with in recent months I must admit, but first thought would be to call rs.exe (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839.aspx) or use the the SSRS webservice methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787(v=sql.120).aspx).

If you mean you want to reference and render the RDL directly without a report server installation presenting the RDL and doing the legwork then I think you need RDLC:

[When to use RDLC over RDL reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079162/when-to-use-rdlc-over-rdl-reports/17070881#17070881)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer(v=vs.100).aspx

[Creating a PDF from a RDLC Report in the Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684221/creating-a-pdf-from-a-rdlc-report-in-the-background)