# SSRS in visual studio: How to use reporting server project as a reference in other projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm not new to C# and Visual Studio, but I'm new to SSRS.

I use Visual Studio 2017, and I have installed the SSRS Plugin. I have created a Report Server Project, added a SQL Database as a Data Source, created a Data Set and created a simple Report, which can be displayed in Preview Mode. I use SQL Server management Studio 2012.

I would like to use the Report to display it in a WPF Application and/or Print it from an application in batch mode etc. but I can't figure out how to, since I don't understand the actual implications of using SSRS. The msdn documentation raises more questions for me than it answers (as usual).

Edit: To be more precise: I want to know how to use the assembly of the Report server project in other Projects. Adding it as a reference is not an option in VS 2017.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This could be helpful to you: [When to use RDLC over RDL reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079162/when-to-use-rdlc-over-rdl-reports)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but yes, it helped me understand a few things. Tahks!

Comment: I am going to guess that you will not get an answer to your question here. It is too broad in scope. SO I meant to answer specific questions. If you were having an issue getting an existing report to work in your application, where you were getting a clear error, we could probably help. But, you are asking how to add reporting to your application, which is no small task. Good luck, though.

Comment: The best way to get an answer here is to add some code to your question.  You have a simple test program it seems.  Give it to us.  You want to connect it to a WPF application. Show us your first attempt.  You will get a quick turn around.  Save printing and batch mode for another question.

Comment: Thank you both for the constructive criticism. Edited the question to make it more precise.